# Вопрос про foreach. PHP

Tags: php, foreach

Как переделать строку `"Дима:56,Андрей:16,Кирилл:24"` в
`"Дима - 56<бр>Андрей - 16<бр>Кирилл - 24<бр>"`

Как такое реализовать на php.
Я учу php, и появилась такая задача, как такое реализовать?

Comment: Как удалить вопрос? Я разобрался

Comment: Сейчас добавлю ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать `explode`. Например так:

```
$text="Дима:56,Андрей:16,Кирилл:24";
$pieces = explode(",", $text);
$newtext="";
foreach ($pieces as $value){
$newtext=$newtext.$value."<br>";

}
```

Или регулярные выражения

```
$text=preg_replace('/,/', '<br>', $text).'<br>';
echo $text;
```

Answer (score 1):

Сначала надо из вашей строки создать ассоциативный массив

```
$string = "Дима:56,Андрей:16,Кирилл:24";

$a = explode(',', $string);  //разделяем на массив

$array = array();

foreach ($a as $result) {
    $b = explode(':', $result);
    $array[$b[0]] = $b[1];  //создаем новый ассоциативный массив 
}
```

потом с помощью команды foreach распечатать

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . " - " . $value . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я реализовал это так

```
$text = "Дима:16,Андрей:23,Антон:17";
$text = explode(',', $text);
foreach($text as $val){
$otvet = explode(':', $val);
echo "{$otvet[0]} - {$otvet[1]}<br>";
}

/*Result
Дима - 16
Андрей - 23
Антон - 17
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = str_replace(array(':', ','),array(' - ',' <br> '),"Дима:16,Андрей:23,Антон:17")
```